# how to fix timeout while creating a file scanner in php

Tags: php, mysqli, web-crawler

Hello guys i am trying to a file scanner and add the data to be saved on the database the files are like 15,000 almost the scanner scans but just half  of the directory the times up.
My code looks like that

```
<?php 
$dir = scandir("manual/");
//saving results
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','test','test123','tests');
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    if ($file != ".." AND $file != "." AND !empty($file)) {
        $coll = explode(".", $file);
        array_pop($coll);
        $fname = $coll['0'];
        $lname = $coll['1'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO `data`(`fname`, `lname`, `directory`) VALUES ('$fname' ,'$lname','$file')";
        //inserting the query into a  sql file
        $db->query($query);
        //data
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can increase the execution time, so to do that you should place this at the top of your PHP script

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Another way to do it, is to change some setting in your php.ini :

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would also suggest that the op could do this in a cron job, checking the date of the files and make this modification for the ini used for cron jobs and command-line commands instead of handling this for HTTP requests.

Comment: I tried that and what happened is that even 300 seconds does not work.
"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in .... on line 20" that is the error that i run into

Comment: "**op could do this in a cron job, checking the date of the files and make this modification for the ini used for cron jobs and command-line commands instead of handling this for HTTP requests**" Can you help me to moderate i did not understand

Comment: @ChrisNgure If you don't know how long it takes your script to run, you can use this line instead `ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', '-1');` at the top of your PHP script